# reader.readAsText fixed file location

Tags: javascript

How can i prevent user from choosing file to be read and make it fixed to specific file this my code:

```
         onLoadFile = function(e) {
         var file = e.target.files[0]; 
           if (!file) {
            return;
               }
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function(e) { 
               return false;
                };
                reader.readAsText(file); 
                   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The user, not you, is in control of your access to his/her files through the browser. If that weren't the case, it would be a **massive** hole to be exploited by malware.